What tool should I use to create new column in dataframe based on multiple condition
I have column (Column1) in dataframe that contain information about work centers and values that I need to assign names of these work centers in empty column (Column2), example:
Input:



Column1:
Column2:




WC1
NaN


123
NaN


456
NaN


789
NaN


abc
NaN


fgh
NaN


WC2
NaN


123
NaN


abc
NaN


123
NaN



Output:



Column1:
Column2:




WC1
WC1


123
WC1


456
WC1


789
WC1


abc
WC1


fgh
WC1


WC2
WC2


123
WC2


abc
WC2


123
WC2



I tried many things and read famous DON'T https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758 but still can't understand what should I use because I want loop to go through every row one by one to assign WC1 only to top values and when loop will find WC2 it will stop assigning WC1 to values

Use Series.where with filter rows with WC value by Series.str.contains and forward non missing values by Series.ffill:
df['Column2'] = df['Column1'].where(df['Column1'].str.contains('WC')).ffill()
print (df)
  Column1 Column2
0     WC1     WC1
1     123     WC1
2     456     WC1
3     789     WC1
4     abc     WC1
5     fgh     WC1
6     WC2     WC2
7     123     WC2
8     abc     WC2
9     123     WC2

How it working:
print (df['Column1'].str.contains('WC'))
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6     True
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: Column1, dtype: bool

print (df['Column1'].where(df['Column1'].str.contains('WC')))
0    WC1
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    WC2
7    NaN
8    NaN
9    NaN
Name: Column1, dtype: object


print (df['Column1'].where(df['Column1'].str.contains('WC')).ffill())
0    WC1
1    WC1
2    WC1
3    WC1
4    WC1
5    WC1
6    WC2
7    WC2
8    WC2
9    WC2
Name: Column1, dtype: object

